# Click link, add class on div. Click other div remove class and add again after second

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a class on a div when a link is clicked, but when I click on another link I want to remove the class and add again after 1 second. The purpose is to hide/show a div with CSS.

This is my code:

```
  jQuery('.mapplic-pin').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();


  if(jQuery(this).closest('.mapplic-map').hasClass('active')) {

      jQuery('.mapplic-map').removeClass('active');
  } else {

      jQuery('.mapplic-map').removeClass('active');


      jQuery(this).closest('.mapplic-map').addClass('active');
  }

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can improve your question by providing examples of where you're getting stuck, but to help you along the way, heres some resources:

[The documentation for **jQuery** .click() events](https://api.jquery.com/click/)
and
[and here's **Vanilla JS** onClick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick)

[**jQuery** delay](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) and [**Vanilla JS** setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

Comment: I would comment, but that required 50 reputation. I wanted to help in any way I could. If that's frowned upon I'll delete the answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my code:

jQuery('.mapplic-pin').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

```
  if(jQuery(this).closest('.mapplic-map').hasClass('active')) {

      jQuery('.mapplic-map').removeClass('active');
  } else {

      jQuery('.mapplic-map').removeClass('active');


      jQuery(this).closest('.mapplic-map').addClass('active');
  }
```

});